# SWIFT: touchesEnded not being called when I touch the screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, touches

So I have a tableviewController called SettingsViewController, and it has the following touchesEnded function:

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    print("A")

    super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
    print("B")
    
    if let touch = touches.first {
        print("C")
        let touchLocation = touch.location(in: view)

        // 290 because the width of the view is 414, and the SettingsViewController width gets set to 0.7 * the view width in SlideInTransition.  0.7 * 414 is 289.8
        if touchLocation.x > 290 {
            dismiss(animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

I made the print statement to see if it was being called, which it is not. This view controller is presented with a 'menu-esque' slide in custom transition.  Is it possible that the bounds of the UIView of the new tablevc displayed with a custom transition is the problem somehow?  Regardless, I have tried implementing super.touchesEnded, or adding all the override touches functions and tapped all over the screen with each simulation, but the touchesEnded never gets called.  Any idea what's wrong and how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: You're using a *"'menu-esque' slide in custom transition"* to present your `SettingsViewController` ... which is a `UITableViewController`? Do you get standard touch events on that table view? Row selection, scrolling, interaction with cell content UI elements, etc?

Comment: Well it's using static cells, as I'm just using it as a settings tab essentially.  So you can tap a button in one of the cells, but no scrolling, row selection, etc.

Comment: Actually that may be misleading, I can tap a cell that just has a label in it and the border line of the cell goes away, I think it's been selected.  Why though? If those aren't enabled is that a problem?

Comment: Are you creating your controllers via code? Or designing them in Storyboard?

Comment: The tableviewController is in my storyboard but instantiated with a string identifier in my code, upon the tap of a button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess that you're putting the `touchesEnded()` func *in your table view controller* ... which is not going to work. The table view itself is consuming the touches.

This might work for you...

Add this `UITableView` subclass to your project:

```
class TouchableTableView: UITableView {
    
    var callback: (() -> ())?
    
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        print("A")
        
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
        print("B")
        
        if let touch = touches.first {
            print("C")
            let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)
            
            // not clear where you're trying to check for touch, so this may need to be changed
            
            // 290 because the width of the view is 414, and the SettingsViewController width gets set to 0.7 * the view width in SlideInTransition.  0.7 * 414 is 289.8
            if touchLocation.x > 290 {
                // this code is in a UITableView subclass,
                //  so we can't call dismiss() from here
                //dismiss(animated: true)

                // instead, we tell the Controller to take action
                callback?()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Then, in Storyboard, select the Table View in your Table View Controller and assign its Custom Class to `TouchableTableView`:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now, `touchesEnded()` will be called in the custom `TouchableTableView` class (unless you tap on an interactive UI element in the cell, such as a button).

We then use the "callback" closure to tell the Controller about the touch. So, in your `UITableViewController`, add this in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
class ExampleTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // we're in a UITableViewController,
        // so make sure the tableView is our TouchableTableView class
        // if it is, setup the closure
        if let tv = tableView as? TouchableTableView {
            tv.callback = {
                // here is where we would, for example, call dismiss()
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, I do have to fix up some  of the actual touch location specificities like you suggested in the code comment, but that is a separate issue. Thanks so much for the help!